# validating a field using jquery

Tags: jquery

rather than using a jquery plugin. if i have two fields and the first field is required and is currently on focus. if i click or tab over to the next field how can i check with jquery to see if the field contains any data and if it doesnt append some text or a class next to it? is onblur() used or?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're close.

You could do something like:

```
$('input[name="data"]').blur(function()
{
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
    {
        // add text or whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, this is so much better than using a plugin. if i wanted to check the field against an expression do i use .type() ? i saw it on the manual of jquery but i dont get how i can use it.

Comment: I think it depends on what you're looking for.  Are wanting to see if it's a regex or if it matches a certain formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Handling the blur event should work just fine. Rough implementation below. You may need to check for whitespaces just in case.

```
$('input[name=firstfield]').blur(function() {
   if ($(this).val().length == 0) { 
      // Add class, text, etc.
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have not misunderstood you can use [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bc954/14/)